# Is there a way to filter a JSON list with jq and remove an attribute from the filtered results with a single command?

Tags: json, bash, command-line-interface, jq

Figured this line works, but uses jq twice:

```bash
cat file.json | jq -c '.[] | select(.property=="undesired")' | jq -c 'del(.property)'
```

Is there a way to invoke jq just once?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just pipe the filters together within a single `jq` command:

```
jq -c '.[] | select(. property=="undesired") | del(.property)' file.json
```